# How to check if right mouse button pressed button?

Tags: javascript, button, input

I've been working all day on this with no progress. Anyways, I've got to build a SIMPLE JavaScript program, since we are only in the beginning phase, basically there should be a button and if I press it with the LEFT mouse button, it should alert("LEFT"), this part is easy because I can use onClick, but I should also check if I pressed the button with the RIGHT mouse button, in that case it should alert("RIGHT"). My struggle comes from the fact that it's easy to check the left button, but how do you actually do it with the right button? It might be a simple problem, but I don't seem to find a correct answer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: To clarify, the answers below will indicate whether the button was the primary mouse action or the tertiary mouse action but the concept of "left" and "right" will be dependant on user preference (i.e. left- or right-handed mouse configuration).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @lukiffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply check the event.button code

0 === left

2 === right

```
document.querySelector(buttonSelector).addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  if(e.button === 0){
    alert('Left') 
 }else if(e.button === 2){
    alert('Right')
 }
```

});

Answer (score 1):

I would add in this 'contextmenu' piece if you don't already have it to prevent the right click context menu from popping up.

```
document.getElementById('buttonID').addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  if (e.button === 0) {
    console.log('Left')
  } else if (e.button === 2) {
    console.log('Right')
  }
});

document.getElementById('buttonID').addEventListener("contextmenu", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```